# How to create DB-Tables on runtime

Tags: web2py

I want to create certain predefined tables when they are needed - let`s say when the user wants to add a certain functionality to an app.

I understand that MODELS "describe data representations" - so i guess my predefined tables have to go here. I tried this in `db.py`:

```
def create_my_table():
    db.define_table('mytesttable',
        Field('mytest', 'text')
            )
```

What I don't understand is, how to call this method. This is not working:

```
{{ =A('Create Table', _href = URL('create_my_table')) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the URL identifies a controller and function within that controller, and the framework runs that function (after executing the model files). You cannot define a function in a model file and then call that function by including its name in a URL. Instead, you should either put the function in a controller, or make a call to your function from a controller.

Also, note that although it is common to define database models in the model files (typically because a given model is often needed in multiple controllers), you can define models anywhere, including in a controller.

Another option is to use the conditional models functionality. For example, you could create a controller action called `create_my_table` in the default.py controller. You can then create a /models/default/create_my_table.py model file, and that model file will only get executed when the /default/create_my_table action is called (in that case, there is no reason to put the model definition inside a function -- just put it at the top level in that model file). You can also define more sophisticated conditional model execution using `response.models_to_run`. For more details, see the relevant [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Workflow).

The latter option might be preferable because when using appadmin, all conditional models are automatically run, so you will have access to the conditionally defined models (appadmin will not have access to tables that are only defined in a specific controller).

Comment: Thanks again for this detailed answer - I will just have to try whats best. But one short question: I tried the conditional model method (corresponding to the controller/action) but ran into an error `Table XYZ already exists` even when calling the standard `index()` action. How comes?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code and the full traceback.